# Mongodb query for list of documents where the value in a particular field has changed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find only the documents where the previous document has a different value for the specific field.

Example docs in collection:

> #1 {'name': 'stack'} 
> #2 {'name': 'stack'} 
> #3 {'name': 'over'} 
> #4 {'name': 'stack'} 
> #5 {'name': 'stack'}

Example query result:

> #2 {'name': 'stack'} 
> #3 {'name': 'over'} 
> #4 {'name': 'stack'}

An iteration via script is not an option.
Is it possible to make this directly with MongoDB-Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your documents exhibits certain sorting, you can use `$setWindowFields` with `$shift` to get the prev document's name. Compare it with the current document and get the "start" of each partition.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        _id: 1
      },
      "output": {
        "prev": {
          $shift: {
            output: "$name",
            by: -1,
            default: null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$name",
          "$prev"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // cosmetics
  {
    $unset: "prev"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eb5V6r2isi-)

---

With MongoDB v4.4 that OP is using, you can `$lookup` prev record by `$sort` and `$limit`. Compare the lookup result with [] or having different name to identify the "start"

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        "currentId": "$_id",
        "currentName": "$name"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$sort": {
            "_id": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$currentId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "prev"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          // first record
          {
            $eq: [
              "$prev",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              "$name",
              {
                "$first": "$prev.name"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "prev"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NKNJUpTecO7)

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be working, thank you.
So my fault i do not ask for mongoDB version 4.4.
Is there a option to for version 4.4?

Comment: @Hesoyam Do you mind sharing your actual sort key? If it is some incremental integer sequence, we might be able to do something with it

Comment: @Hesoyam updated the answer to include an alternative for v4.4

Comment: Sry i am late. I do this for now by script.
I changed a list route to a not paginated get Route.
So i do not have the pain anymore to skip and limit the result to paginate it.

The sort key is "created_at", or alternative the "_id" key (because of the included timestamp).
Both keys are indexed.